# How to disable (Not remove completely) global menu bar?

Tags: unity, 14.04, emacs

While using the text-editors I like to work on text editors with **completely full-screen** mode.

But In almost all editors the `global-menu-bar` of ubuntu Desktop remains on the screen.

[image: Global menu bar]

I ***just want to disable*** it while using the text-editor(Emacs) and once I am done I would like to get it back. I ***don't want to remove it completely***.

I want it to look like this

[image]
How can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

I am using ubuntu 14.04!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy fix.

It is juts <kbd>F11</kbd> !!

Just press <kbd>F11</kbd> after starting emacs and you will get it full screen.!